# GitHub access token scopes for use with AWS SageMaker instances

Tags: security, github, permissions

What are the minimum [scopes](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/understanding-scopes-for-oauth-apps/) I need to assign to my GitHub personal access token in order to to provide my AWS SageMaker instance read/write access to a private GitHub repo?

Answer (score 3):

I gave permissions in the `repo` and `admin:repo_hook` scopes and it works just fine for me.

It may be that only one of the two are necessary, but it wasn't clear and I couldn't find documentation (as of this writing.)

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, SageMaker notebooks only needs permission to clone your Git repo before the notebook instance is accessible. Once you're able to manually interact with the notebook notebook instance, it's up to you on what additional Git commands to run (pull, commit, etc).

For private repos, you will need the **repo** scope permission.